# Ondemand javascript call on window unload using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried for "unload" and "beforeunload" binding in following code, but none of the browser is sending a request:

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
       $.ajax({cache: false,
        dataType: "script",
            url: "test.php"
        });
    });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which browser are you running this in? For a long time, Safari had issues with properly implementing `unload` handlers. Not sure if that's still true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser doesn't wait for this code to finish...it's running just fine :) Add an `alert('hi')` to see it running.

The problem you're seeing is typical of `unload` issues, the browser navigates away well before a request gets fired off in your case...and it should really, no code you're running should have to complete before I'm allowed to move onto the next page.  This is just how `unload` behaves.  You could make the call synchronous to hold the user there, but please **don't** do this.

The `unload` event was created on window mainly to clean up anything left around in the DOM you needed to, more-so when garbage collection wasn't as good as it is now (and still isn't in IE)...it wasn't really designed with AJAX or metric tracking in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the option async to false.

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
   $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    dataType: "script",
        url: "test.php"
    });
});
```