# retrieve logout time without logout

Tags: java, session, servlets, httpsession

how can i see logout time when user closes the browser without logout?

So i implemented `HttpSessionBindingListener` taken from [here](http://tunatore.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/how-to-define-a-httpsessionbindinglistener-for-a-j2ee-web-application/) and added `Listener in web.xml` but logout time is not being inserted into database after closing browser. Any suggestion please where i am wrong?

logout.jsp

```
 <%
    ObjectWillBeInSession owi = new ObjectWillBeInSession();
    owi.setProperty1("I am a value for Property1");
    owi.setProperty2("I am a value for Property2");
    //this will call HttpSessionBindingListener's 
    //valueBound method for the object
    session.setAttribute("owi", owi);

    //this will call HttpSessionBindingListener's 
    //valueUnbound method for the object
    session.removeAttribute("owi");   
        //INSERT INTO DB.......BUT IT IS NOT WORKING
 %>
```

Comment: One option is to implement unload event handler as explained in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621927/ondemand-javascript-call-on-window-unload-using-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621927/ondemand-javascript-call-on-window-unload-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Closing the browser does not trigger any request to the server, so there is no way you can know that the user closed his browser.
You can use a listener to way for the session to time out and then store the current time when that happens. Session typically expire hours after the last request from the client, though.

Comment: yes `session` is getting invalidated after 30 mins as given in `web.xml` how can i know this session invalid time in logout.jsp?

Comment: You can implement a SessionListener (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and store the current time when `sessionDestroyed` is called.

Comment: thanks Mathias for your answer i am trying to implement your method

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `window.onbeforeunload` to send an AJAX request to a servlet to record the time the user closed the browser and do what you need in the session object.

Comment: onbeforeunload will not only be called when the browser is closed.

Comment: thanks Behrooz for your answer but can you please add little bit more to your answer so that i can implement it, how should i use this `window.onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: isn't onbeforeunload nonstandard?

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz , I agree. But either `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.onunload` can be useful.

Comment: @Tom, maybe [this](http://www.metamorphosite.com/time-site-javascript-send-synchronous-request-php) could be helpful to you. You need to tailor to Java world.

Comment: `onunload` is the standard name for the property. I just don't see how it is useful: this event is fired _every_ time the user navigates away from a page, so it won't be useful for what @Tom is trying to do.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz, totally agree. So, the trick could be to use the last time that such event is recorded from the user side. I think it should be accompanied with a timer on the session time-out initial parameter value in `web.xml`.